# Tensorflow 2: How to compute forward jacobian for chain of bijectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I have a collection of Tensorflow 2 Bijectors `b0, b1, bN` and I have constructed a derived Bijector class that consists of a chain of a bunch of primitive Bijectors, thus:

```
class MyBijector( Bijector ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.bChain = tfb.Chain( [ b0, b1, ... bN ] )
```

Do I have to define the `_forward_log_det_jacobian` for this explicitly or does Tensorflow figure out how to do this for me?  If I have to define it, can someone please
remind me how the "chain rule" works in this case?

Comment: `MyBijector` will have [__call__](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/bijectors/Bijector#__call__) method which you can easily get a chain instance (i.e: bij1(bij2)). If that's not really what you are asking, please clarify a bit more.

Comment: I really have two questions:   First, assuming I just say "b = tfb.Chain([b1,b2])" (that is, without defining a new class) does Tensorflow 2 "just know" how to calculate "call" or do I have to define it myself.   Second, if I do have to define it myself, how do I define the "forward_log_det_jacobian", that is, how do I use the "chain rule" to do this?

Comment: AFAIK TF2 should know how do it itself, you don't need to re-define it.

Comment: It appears from the examples in the doc.s about "tfb.Chain" that you're right.  Thanks.

Comment: I added this as an answer. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

> I really have two questions: First, assuming I just say "b =
> tfb.Chain([b1,b2])" (that is, without defining a new class) does
> Tensorflow 2 "just know" how to calculate "call" or do I have to
> define it myself. Second, if I do have to define it myself, how do I
> define the "forward_log_det_jacobian", that is, how do I use the
> "chain rule" to do this?

`MyBijector` will have `__call__` method which you can easily get a chain instance (i.e: `bij1(bij2)`).

In other words, TensorFlow knows how do it itself, you don't need to re-define it.